# web3.eth.getBalance(address) throws an error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: web3js, accounts, nodejs

```
var web3 =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.getBalance(address)
```

throws an error:

> Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

while `address` is some existing valid address.

geth is running.

What could possibly cause that?

Comment: What is your geth command line? Is rpc interface enabled? It should be something like `geth --rpc <other options>`.

Comment: @Ismael no just geth. Is that the problem? Are you sure? Because I do manage to create accounts via web3, but not to get their balances. This code does work: web3.eth.accounts.create();

Comment: Did you try to launch geth with said command line option?

Comment: @Ismael yes I did and I don't get this error anymore, thank you. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.